# React material UI Menuitem contentElement shows error

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

Just came across these two code, first one works for me while second one gives me an error:

Working Code:

```
<MenuItem
  key={index}
  style={styles.menuItem}
  leftIcon={menu.icon}
>
  <NavLink to={menu.link}>{menu.text}</NavLink>
</MenuItem>
```

Error Code:

```
<MenuItem
  key={index}
  style={styles.menuItem}
  primaryText={menu.text}
  leftIcon={menu.icon}
  containerElement={<Link to={menu.link} />}
 />
```

Now the question is, why do I get an error for my later part and not for the first. I am using react router 4.

Thanks in advance for any explanation.

Comment: Looking at their docs it seems that `MenuItem` doesn't have `containerElement` prop. Which version are you using? Also, could you be more specific about which error message is it throwing up?

Comment: I am using "material-ui": "^0.19.1", and I think you are right, my bad. I miss took the containerElement property.